# Why does document.ready fire after click event

Tags: jquery

I have a basic slideshow created for my home page.

After loading the document correctly I click on my tag to fire the click event. It runs correctly but then the document load runs afterwards and resets everything back to the beginning.

Its probably quite obvious but I can't see the problem. Here is the code:

```
function forwardClick(){
    var Links = loadLinks();
    imgNumber = currentImgNumber();
    //now calculate the next Id
    imgNumber = Math.min(Links.length - 1, imgNumber + 1);
    nextSlider(imgNumber, Links);
}

function nextSlider(imgNumber, Links){

    //set the link for current slide
    populateLinkAndImage(Links, imgNumber);

    //replace the text of the hidden field with the current imgNum
    $('#counter').html(imgNumber.toString());
}

function populateLinkAndImage(Links, imgNumber){
    //now replace the existing image and text with the correct ones for the current imgNumber
    $("#imgHolder").attr("src", Links[imgNumber]["imgLink"]);
    $("#linkHolder").attr("href", Links[imgNumber]["aLink"]);
    $("#linkHolder").html(Links[imgNumber]["text"]);
}

function loadLinks(){
    var Links = [];
    var link0 = { imgLink: "Images/L/ipad.jpg", text: "Use our In Depth Guide to create a super profitable Hair and Beauty Salon", aLink: "P/Managing/Running-The-Perfect-Hair-Salon.aspx" };
    var link1 = { imgLink: "Images/L/ipad-sample-2.jpg", text: "Starting, buying or planning a new Cafe, build a rock solid plan here", aLink: "P/Managing/CafePlanner.aspx" };
    Links.push(link0);
    Links.push(link1);

    return Links;
}

function currentImgNumber(){
    //first find id number of current image loaded
    //could use hidden field or loop through the array to find its index
    //using hidden field
    imgText = $("#counter").html();
    imgNumber = parseInt(imgText, 10);
    return imgNumber;
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    var Links = loadLinks();

    //set the link for current slide
    populateLinkAndImage(Links, 0, "");

    //set the user interaction events
    $(".next").click(function () {
        forwardClick();
    });

});
```

Thanks for looking

Comment: Your page is likely reloading when the link is clicked, which causes everything to start over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to prevent default behaviour for link tag:

```
$(".next").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        forwardClick();
    });
```